# Why is this variable acting like a pointer in Javascript? (using HTML5 Canvas)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

[Here is a demo](http://www.drewblaisdell.com/tint)

Specifically, this is the part I find confusing:

```
$('.red').change(function(){
    pix = imageData.data;

    for(var i = 0, n = pix.length; i < n; i += 4){
        var green = 1, blue = 1;
        pix[i] = pix[i] * $(this).val();
        pix[i + 1] = pix[i + 1] * green;
        pix[i + 2] = pix[i + 2] * blue;
    }
    context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
});
```

How is it that modifying pix (which should be in the global scope) modifies the imageData object? Javascript does not directly support pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Javascript does not directly support pointers.

No, but [it is a reference](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass), which has very similar semantics.  You're not creating a copy in that assignment.  Objects are passed by reference, primitive types by value.

Comment: Ahh. I thought this was how they worked in JS, but I couldn't delete the object because I had previously defined it in a scope up the hierarchy so I thought there was some weird pointer magic going on. Excellent.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, objects are passed around by reference. They are never copied.